# React rerender on prop change

Tags: reactjs, redux, rerender

My problem is when I change a state inside a redux store and based on this state I mount or unmount a component. The Code looks like this:

```js
class Main extends Component {

  render() {
    const { dropdownState } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <SecondHeadBar />
        <div className="main">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={withRouter(WebsiteIndex)}/>
            <Route path='/track/:trackid' component={withRouter(MssTrack)}/>
            <Route path='/album/:albumid' component={withRouter(Container.AlbumContainer)}/>
            <Route path='/profile/:userName' component={withRouter(MssUser)}/>
            <Route path='/upload/:albumid' component={withRouter(MssUploadTemplate)}/>
            <Route path='/upload' component={withRouter(MssUploadTemplate)}/>
            <Route path='/admin' component={withRouter(ControlCenter)}/>
            <Route path='/kategorie' component={withRouter(Category)} exact/>
            <Route path='/kategorie/:catName' component={withRouter(Folder)}/>
            <Route path='/notFound' component={withRouter(NotFound)}/>
            <Route path='/meine-eintraege' component={withRouter(Container.MyEntriesContainer)}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
        {dropdownState ? <DownloadDropdown /> : ''}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    dropdownState: state.collection.dropdownState
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatch
  };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);
```

Whenever the prop `dropdownState` changes. And the Component `DownloadDropdown` gets mounted then everything in the `Main` Component gets rerendered. So the content flashes.

Comment: What is your problem exactly ?

Comment: Sry if it is not clear. Whenever the prop dropdownState changes. And the Component DownloadDropdown gets mounted the everything i the render() function gets rerendered. So the content flashes becouse it is loading async from an API

Comment: @ArnaudChrist i changed the question a bit. Hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: Rather than unmounting and remounting `DownloadDropdown`, it might be a better idea to pass `dropdownState` into it as a prop, then let it decide when it needs to rerender/call to the server.

Comment: @JoeClay I though of this too but i dont know if it is a bad practice becouse then would be DownloadDropdown allways mounted.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to pass `mapDispatchToProps` if you only want `dispatch`. It is passed in by default if you do not provide `mapDispatchToProps`, i.e., `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Main)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution would be to have `<DownloadDropdown />` be a container component that is connected to `Redux` and will always stay mounted **although not visible**. Then you can utilize a `HOC` or something that's always mounted and visible (like `<SecondHeadBar />`) and have it connected to a Redux `action creator` that toggles `DownloadDropdown`'s visiblity. In other words, isolate Redux to two components, instead of over your entire route tree.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/yw4m7yz8r1 (navigate around the routes and click the 'Download Schedule' link at the top!)

I'm not sure how you are triggering the mount/unmount, but let's stay it's being toggled by a button:

**SecondHeadBar.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { handleDropdown } from '../actions';

class SecondHeadBar extends Component {
  state = {...}

  componentDidMount = () => { ... }

  render = () => (
    <div>
      ...
      <button onClick={this.props.handleDropdown}>Toggle Dropdown</button>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}

export default connect(null, { handleDropdown })(SecondHeadBar)
```

**DownloadDropdown.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class DownloadDropdown extends Component {
  state = { ... }

  componentDidMount = () => { ... }


  render = () => (
    this.props.isVisible
      ? <div>I'm visible!</div>
      : null
  )
}

export default connect(state => ({ isVisible: state.dropdown }))(DownloadDropdown)
```

**actions.js**

```
import { TOGGLE_DROPDOWN } from '../types'


export const handleDropdown = () => ({
  type: TOGGLE_DROPDOWN
})
```

**reducers.js**

```
import { TOGGLE_DOWN } from '../types';

...

const dropdownReducer = (state=false, { type, payload }) => {
  switch(type) {
    case TOGGLE_DROPDOWN: return !state
    default: return state
  }
}

export default = combineReducer({
  ...
  dropdown: dropdownReducer
  ...
})
```

**routes.js**

```
const Main = () => (
  <div>
    <SecondHeadBar />
    <div className="main">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={withRouter(WebsiteIndex)}/>
        <Route path='/track/:trackid' component={withRouter(MssTrack)}/>
        <Route path='/album/:albumid' component={withRouter(Container.AlbumContainer)}/>
        <Route path='/profile/:userName' component={withRouter(MssUser)}/>
        <Route path='/upload/:albumid' component={withRouter(MssUploadTemplate)}/>
        <Route path='/upload' component={withRouter(MssUploadTemplate)}/>
        <Route path='/admin' component={withRouter(ControlCenter)}/>
        <Route path='/kategorie' component={withRouter(Category)} exact/>
        <Route path='/kategorie/:catName' component={withRouter(Folder)}/>
        <Route path='/notFound' component={withRouter(NotFound)}/>
        <Route path='/meine-eintraege' component={withRouter(Container.MyEntriesContainer)}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
    <DownloadDropdown/>
  </div>
);

export default Main;
```

Now, when the user clicks the "Toggle Dropdown" button in `<SecondHeadBar/>`, it'll update `<DownloadDropdown/>`'s visibility without affecting your route tree.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use this lifecycle methods to check.

```
 static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        if (nextProps.name !== prevState.name) {
            return { name: nextProps.name};
        }
    }
```

or for older version check in `componentwillreceiveProps` and stops re render.